# how to set up sqlite with visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am setting up a program that requires communicating to a database, but I can not figure out how to set up SQLite for c++ in my ide, I can figure out the rest from there, but the guides are incomplete or inconclusive.

I have tried to work with the api but could not figure out how to install it into my ide, what should i download to get the code for SQLite cpp.

Comment: Probably `sqlite-amalgamation-3300100.zip` here is what that contains: https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you can use dotnet.exe but it's done like this
.Not all projects have these options. Too check project try this command.

Dotnet new webapp -?
Dotnet new mvc -?
Dotnet new winforms -?

Will show -uld |--use-local-db you must use -au Individual

Like this
Dotnet new webapp -au  Individual  -uld
For SQL server

And Dotnet new webapp -au  Individual
For Sqlite.